# Detecting if a mouse is wireless

Tags: java, language-agnostic, mouse

I am trying to detect whether a wireless mouse is present on a computer. I would like my program to run in the background. I would prefer to do this in Java however if this goes beyond Java's capabilities I can use another language.

Can someone please get me started?

(This seems like a Google-able question but I cannot find anything)

Answer (score 1):

This is beyond Java and is highly OS-specific. You have to query the appropriate device drivers for the operating system; for example, on Linux this would mean looking up information in the `evdev` system. Note that the particular "type" of wireless will matter a lot, and you may not be able to tell in any reliable way. For example, a Bluetooth mouse is always wireless, but some wireless devices connect with a USB dongle and may not be distinguishable from a wired USB device.

Comment: Just curious, do USB devices ever give a name? Like could I see that "ACME Wireless Mouse" was connected on port 4?

Comment: Sure, they have user-friendly names (`lsusb -v` on Linux will show you lots of interesting info), but you can't rely on them.

Comment: OK thanks. I think your answer and the answer above give me enough to get started.